# メンバ変数全てに値が格納されていることを知る良い方法

Tags: java

あるクラスがAからZまでのメンバ変数を持っている場合、そのメンバ変数全てに値が格納されていることを判定する良い方法はないでしょうか。

```
class Test{
 public String A;
 public String B;
 public List<String> C;
 .
 .
 .
}
```

上記のようなクラスを判定メソッドhasAllAttributes()を作成する場合

```
boolean hasAllAttributes(){
   if(A == null ||
      B == null ||
      .
      .
      .){
      return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

のように判定するしかないのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 例えば`EnumSet`のようなものを使ってそれぞれのフィールドに値のセットをしたかどうかの管理をするとかすればどうでしょうか。

Comment: @BLUEPIXY 回答ありがとうございます。EnumSetというよりもEnumMapで変数名と格納済みフラグで管理できそうですね。http://www.techscore.com/tech/Java/JavaSE/JavaLanguage/4-3/
しかし、クラスそのものの管理は大変になりそうです。
クラスのメンバ変数を一括で取得するなどはできないのでしょうか。

Comment: [Class#getDeclaredFields()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/7/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29)のようなもの(`public` だけが対象の場合は`getFields`)ですか？

Comment: @BLUEPIXY そうです！私の求めていたのは現状ではそれです。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@BLUEPIXさんの回答より
Class#getDeclaredFields()で可能である。

先ほどのhasAllAttributes()を改良すると以下になる。

```
boolean hasAllAttributes(){
   for (Field field : this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
      if(field.get(this)==null){
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```